# zend site needs alias too

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a zend site where DocRoot is set to public/ and URL as 
(http://dothat.com/controllerA/action9/) - which is working properly.

I also need to run a copy of that site on the same server as 
(http://dothat.com/now/controllerA/action9/) running on same folder.

(The urls given are examples)

Please suggest on how can this be done without spoiling zend setup itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally just do a simple Zend route in your Bootstrap.

Example:

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{   
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');

    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

    $nowRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route("now/:controller/:action");

    $frontController->getRouter()->addRoute("now", $nowRoute);
}
```

Routes in Zend are very powerful and fun to setup.  I actually have mine in an outside .ini file to make it easier to setup, even environment aware.

Answer (score 2):

it's working for me

/etc/httpd/conf.d/zendproject.conf

```
Alias /zendproject/ /var/www/vhosts/zendproject/public/

<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/zendproject/public/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

public/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /zendproject/index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about that idea:

An alias in Apache (if it's the http server you're using)

```
Alias /now /path/to/zend/public   
<Directory /path/to/zend/public>      
  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
  ...
</Directory>
```

And you have to care for the .htacces too

```
...
RewriteRule ^.*$ /now/index.php [NC,L]
```

E.g. with another environmental variable for the path in the rewrite rule..

Comment: When i used Alias, its the RewriteRule/Cond which I could not get correctly. the rule should honour the existing site (/) and also the new site (/now).

Comment: Like i said you can use another server environmental.. SetEnv PATH / and SetEnv PATH /now and use that env in your htaccess e.g. http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-variable-fun-in-htaccess.html